# Can't interact with ClearDB hosted on Heroku

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, cleardb

So I'm setting a connection like this:

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", 'us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net');
define("DB_USER", 'bc2****06bc220');
define("DB_PASS", '04****ae08');
define("DB_NAME", 'heroku_7da****a5ce8ba');   
?>
```

Then I made a dump (localhost.sql) of my database and I'm executing it like this:

```
"mysql --host=us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net --user=bc2dc****6bc220 --reconnect heroku_7****4ca5ce8ba < localhost.sql"
```

It doesn't give any errors after this.

But then nothing else:
http://ajaxaddressbook.herokuapp.com/

There's supposed to be some displayed data, and when I'm trying to add anything it gives me the next errors:

> GET http://ajaxaddressbook.herokuapp.com/contacts.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> POST http://ajaxaddressbook.herokuapp.com/add_contact.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

This for example is how I'm trying to add a contact(I'm using PDO):

```
<?php include 'core/init.php'; ?>
<?php 
//Create DB Object
$db = new Database;

//Run Query
$db->query("INSERT INTO `addressbook_contacts` (first_name, last_name, email, phone, address1, address2, city, state,  zipcode, contact_group, notes)
            VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zipcode, :contact_group, :notes)");

//Bind Values
if($_POST){
    $db->bind(':first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
    $db->bind(':last_name', $_POST['last_name']);
    $db->bind(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $db->bind(':phone', $_POST['phone']);
    $db->bind(':address1', $_POST['address1']);
    $db->bind(':address2', $_POST['address2']);
    $db->bind(':city', $_POST['city']);
    $db->bind(':state', $_POST['state']);
    $db->bind(':zipcode', $_POST['zipcode']);
    $db->bind(':contact_group', $_POST['contact_group']);
    $db->bind(':notes', $_POST['notes']);
    
    if($db->execute()){
        echo "Contact was added";
    } else{
        echo "Could not add contact";
    }
} else{
    echo "Could not add contact";
}

?>
```

I've checked everything and it's working fine on my localhost, all as supposed but if I'm trying to connect to a ClearDB hosted on Heroku it doesn't work.

p.s. I have this in composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "ext-mysql": "*"
    }
}
```

p.s.s. Here is my PDO class:

```
<?php
    class Database{
        private $host   = DB_HOST;
        private $user   = DB_USER;
        private $pass   = DB_PASS;
        private $dbname = DB_NAME;
        
        private $dbh;
        private $error;
        private $stmt;   
        
        public function __construct(){
            // Set DSN
            /*
             * A data source name (DSN) is a data structure that contains the information about a specific database that an Open Database Connectivity ( ODBC ) driver needs in order to connect to it. 
             */
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
            // Set Options
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
            // Create a new PDO instance
            try{
                $this -> dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
            }   // Catch any Errors
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            };
        }
        
        public function query($query){
            $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        }
        
        public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
            if(is_null ( $type )){
                switch(true){
                    case is_int ($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    case is_bool ($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    case is_null ($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                    default:
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
            }
            $this->stmt->bindValue ($param, $value, $type);
        }
        
        public function execute(){
            return $this->stmt->execute();
        }
        
        public function resultset(){
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        
        public function single(){
            $this -> execute();
            return $this->stmt-> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        
        public function rowCount(){
            return $this->stmt->rowCount();
        }
        
        public function lastInsertId(){
            return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
        }
        
        };
?>
```

p.s.s.s. Iv'e caught this PDO exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'heroku_7da7af4ca5ce8ba.addressbook_contacts' doesn't exist' in /app/libraries/Database.php:54
```

It looks like my dump was not executed and database on Heroku server is empty?